# spark truncates timestamp when writing json

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, timestamp

when writing a timestamp column of a Spark DataFrame to JSON microseconds are truncated:

```scala
val df = Seq("2019-09-30 00:08:27.272846").toDF("dt").select(col("dt").cast("timestamp"))
df.show(false) // prints 2019-09-30 00:08:27.272846
df.write.json("/tmp/spark/dt")
val dff = spark.read.json("/tmp/spark/dt")
dff.show(false) // prints 2019-09-30T00:08:27.272Z
```

Is this the expected behavior?

https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL2R2aXJ0ekBnbWFpbC5jb20vNGFkZGI1ZDEyZTFlNDJmNTkwMzIyNDg1ODc3ZGI0ZTUvbm90ZS5qc29u

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It's expected behaviour!

When we cast to **`timestamp type`** while writing json file to HDFS location spark truncates and keep only **`3 digits in millisecs`**.

> **How to get column value without truncating?**

Cast to **`string type`** and write data to HDFS.

```
val df = Seq("2019-09-30 00:08:27.272846").toDF("dt").select(col("dt").cast("string"))
df.write.json("/tmp/spark/dt")
val dff = spark.read.json("/tmp/spark/dt")
dff.show(false)
```

`Result:`

```
+--------------------------+
|dt                        |
+--------------------------+
|2019-09-30 00:08:27.272846|
+--------------------------+
```

**`(or)`**

```
val df = Seq("2019-09-30 00:08:27.272846").toDF("dt").select(col("dt").cast("timestamp"))

//add new column to get last 3 digits from dt column

val df1 = df.withColumn("ms",expr("substring(dt,-3)")).show(false)
```

then write **`df1 to HDFS`** location in json format and when you read the json file again **concat** **`dt + ms`** fields to recreate your **`original timestamp`** value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @shu. Do you have any reference for that being expected? Seems strange that writing to JSON behaves differently than to Parquet.